# Create data frame from pictures data in R

Tags: r, azure, dataframe, face-recognition

I need create data frame from pictures , namely split pictures on the parameters. I use Azure cognitive service

```
q <- "?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=true&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,smile,headPose,facialHair,glasses,emotion"
url1 <- paste( q, sep="")


#path to my folder with pictures
pic1="C:/pictures" #here some pictures
library("httr")
#send the request to Face API
# my keys calls FaceRecognition
response = POST(url=url1, body=pic1, add_headers(.headers = 
c('Content-Type'='application/octet-stream', 'FaceRecognition'='12345...32')))

result <- content(response)
result
df <- as.data.frame(result)


# pivot the data frame...you need to add package reshape2 for this
library("reshape2")
df2 <- melt(df, id=c("faceId"))
```

So After i get the error

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : <url> malformed
```

and

```
Error: id variables not found in data: faceId
```

But i want get dataframe like
[image]

and then transpose dataframe like this
[image]

How to get such output

## Note

Azure is not a panacea for me, I took it as an example to practice, if you know an easier way to get the desired output, I will be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you're pasting one string. paste takes multiple arguments and concatenates them into a single character object using sep to separate them.  so url1 is just q, which is, indeed, a malformed url, since there is no protocol (e.g. http://) or url (i.e. example.com/face-recognition-endpoint).  the rest is a result of that.

try adding adding a url to your paste statement, e.g.

```
base <- "https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/identify"
q <- "?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=true&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,smile,headPose,facialHair,glasses,emotion"
url1 <- paste(base, q, sep = "")
```

then, for the POST command, you need to specify that you are uploading a file, and i'm guessing azure only wants one file at a time, so you'll need something like

```
pic1 <- "C:/pictures/pic1.jpeg"
response <- POST(url = url1, body = upload_file(pic1) ...)
```

Comment: your link it is for microsoft. How can i add my link, without microsoft

Comment: The azure face recognition API is offered by Microsoft. Other products would have their own endpoints. You'll have to look at the documentation for the service you wish to use.